# SQL server connection string

Tags: server, mysql, sql

Is it possible to somehow get connection string to my SQL server ? It is running localy, on the same computer as my app which need to use the sql server do.

So far the application has been running on windows, with connection string :

```
Data Source=JOHN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=knihovna;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;
```

Comment: Where do you use the connection string? Is the database mysql? What app is it?

Comment: The application is asp.net core 2.1. I use it in appsteting.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [mysql documentation](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/net-core-mvc/):

> ```
>    "ConnectionStrings": {
>     "DefaultConnection": "server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=pass;port=3306;database=blog;"
> }
> ```

You will obviously have to replace the password, username and database to suit your needs.

Comment: It seems not to suport keyword "port". Anyway what port is that 3306 of ?

Comment: 3306 is the default password for MySQL. The connection string you posted indicates you used it with SQL Server Express on Windows... Are you able to provide more context?

Comment: It is working now. Even without the port. Thank you :-)